# Counting in 25 Times Table PHP

Tags: php

How can i count from 0 to 10,000 in the 25 times table for example

```
$page = array(0, 25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, and so on...);
```

But i can't be bothered to write 0 to 10,000 lol so is there a easier way for me to do this?.

Comment: `for($i=0; $i<=1000; $i+=25){ $page[]=$i; }` as easy as that, that's why there are computers and programming

Comment: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

Comment: `$page = range(0, 10000, 25);`

Comment: Or in php you can use `$array = range(0,1000,25);` as described in http://fr2.php.net/range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try http://www.php.net/range

```
$page = range(0, 10000, 25);
```

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

Example:

```
foreach (range(0, 10000, 25) as $number) {
    echo $number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
$page=array();
$i=0;
for($i = 0 ; $i <= 10000 ; $i = $i + 25)
{
    array_push($page,$i);   // add 25 time element one by one.
}

// use $page array for your use
```